# Customize Authorize Redirect

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am using Beta 4 and when I use the [Authorize] attribute, it redirects to /account/login like i'd expect but that's no the name of my URL. I could customize this in web.config but I don't know where to configure it in ASP.NET 5. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will help but I did download VS 2015 RC.

I’ve created a new **MVC 6 website** project and launched (F5) it. While being **unauthenticated**, I tried reaching the `ManageController` which is decorated with the `[Authorize]` attribute.

Needless to say, I was redirected to the Account/login view but nowhere have I found where this is configured.

I did manage to add the following inside the `ConfigureServices()` method of the `Startup.cs`:

```cs
services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Gazou/Index");
    });
```

Just above the:

```cs
services.AddMvc();
```

I’ve then created my new `GazouController` with a simple `Index IActionResult()`.

Ran the application again, tried accessing the `ManageController` but this time, I was redirected to the `Index` method of my `GazouController` instead of the default behavior.

Hope this helps.
Vince

Comment: I am also looking for the same answer "Needless to say, I was redirected to the Account/login view but nowhere have I found where this is configured." does any one know why it is redirected and having such behavior with our configuration

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't format it with code so I can't see it, but this is what I found:

```
  services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(opt =>
  {
    opt.LoginPath = PathString.FromUriComponent("/Auth/Login");
  });
```